# failed during adding a partition in hive external tables

Tags: hadoop, hive

im trying to create a simple external table in hive cli and I got an error while creating a partition. I have searched on google, but I was not able to get a proper result. Can you please help

```
hive (sampledb)> create external table externalhive(id int,name varchar(100),age tinyint,city varchar(100),state varchar(100)) partitioned by (year string)
            > row format delimited fields terminated by '/t' stored as textfile location '/user/ah12x/external';                                      
OK
Time taken: 0.169 seconds
hive (sampledb)> show tables;
OK
externalhive

hive (sampledb)> alter table externalhive add partition (year ='2014')
            > location ('/2012');                                  
FAILED: ParseException line 2:9 extraneous input '(' expecting StringLiteral near '<EOF>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for braces after `location`, https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTable/PartitionLocation